# Lower estimate for $(\frac{\ln(1+2x)}{\ln(1+x)}-1)(1+2x)^{1/2}$ where $x>0$

Tags: calculus, inequality, logarithms

I want to prove that:
$$\left(\frac{\ln(1+2x)}{\ln(1+x)}-1\right)(1+2x)^\frac{1}{2}\geq 1$$
where $x>0$. Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Assuming $x > 0$ I guess?

Comment: Yes, thanks Raclette!

Comment: This inequality is not only true for $x > 0$, but also for $x > -\frac{1}{2}$. The problem was well-posed before without the constraint $x >0$, if we had considered $x$ in the range domain of $ln (1+2x)$.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a not very beautiful solution.

As $x > 0$, it is equivalent to show that
$$\log\left(1 + \frac{x}{1 + x}\right)\sqrt{1 + 2 x} - \log(1 + x) \geq 0.$$
As LHS $\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow 0$, it is enough to show that the LHS is increasing as a function of $x$. That is, that its derivative is greater than $0$ for $x > 0$. Differentiating, we obtain the inequality
$$\frac{1 - \sqrt{1 + 2 x} + (1 + x) \log\left(1 + \frac{x}{1 + x}\right)}{(1 + x) \sqrt{1 + 2 x}} \geq 0.$$
It is of course enough to show that 
$$1 - \sqrt{1 + 2 x} + (1 + x) \log\left(1 + \frac{x}{1 + x}\right)\geq 0.$$
By the same argument (i.e., limit when $x\rightarrow 0$ is $0$, so it is enough to show LHS is increasing as a function of $x$),
differentiating, it is enough to show that
$$\frac{1}{1 + 2 x} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + 2 x}} + \log\left(1 + \frac{x}{1 + x}\right) \geq 0.$$
By the same argument yet again (sorry!), it is enough to show that
$$\frac{1 - \sqrt{1 + 2 x} + x (3 + 2 x)}{(1 + x) (1 + 2 x)^{\frac{5}{2}}} \geq 0.$$
So it is enough to show that
$$1 - \sqrt{1 + 2 x} + x (3 + 2 x) \geq 0.$$
But this one is easy!

Comment: Thanks a bunch, Raclette. It was very very helpful, indeed!

Comment: To me, it is a very beautiful and detailed answer! Thanks for your time again!